# How to: Sharepoint 2010 to Office 365 migration

Tags: 2010, 2013, office-365, migration

Are there any tutorials / walkthroughs for migration from SharePoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013 in Office 365?
Specifically for the below points:
1. JQuery migration from Sharepoint 2010 to Office 365.
2. Workflow Migration.
3. XSLT Migrations.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd party applications that can do this for you.

Not sure if you can take the Workflows also tho.

SP 2010 WF are a bit different that 2013 WF and I don't know if it can be done.